# C# How to use class to execute Window's Form order sequence

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio, class

I'm creating a Quiz in C# which consists of five question styles (textbook, true false, multiple choice, combobox, & drag-drop ).

Similarly, there are five question topics (geography, history, culture, sport, general knowledge).

Each question style must be used once in an instance of playing the quiz i.e. the quiz has five questions. The question styles and the question topics are randomised each time the quiz is played.

I have a shuffle created using a list with the question styles & a separate list for the question topics.

How would I use a class to order the question styles and load their respective forms, then return and load the next question form and so on for each five question styles? or is there a better alternative?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! : )

Comment: Seems like the Topic should be a property of the Question.  Same for Style.  Then to be sure you have one of each, pick a random one of each from the master list, then 3 more totally at random

Comment: So you have class file in which you want to shuffle quiz type(history, sport...) and quiz style (textbox, true-false...) so only 1 type is for 1 style. After that user will open forms 1 by 1 (i mean first form opens and then by finishing it, it goes to the next form) or all at once or all quiz is at the same form?

Comment: @DoLoop one topic for each style. the styles are individual forms which I want to load one at a time, the user answers the questions, presses next btn and the class I'm trying to develop will load the next form style that is in the list, and so on. I'm trying to come up with a way to order this transition between random question styles (forms).

Answer (score 0):

First create array of 5 integers. Then on creating first form (let's say for geographic) you request on creating for `int type` and you give it random number. When get random number, you check if that number exists in array you created, and if it doesn't you create `geo form` and add that number to array and pass that array to new form. Then same method on second form, get random number, check if that number exists in array and if not, you create new let's say `history form` and add new number to array.

And when adding questions you just say that number 1 = textboxes, 2 = true-false ...

Like this order for topic will be always same but their questions type will be different. If you think a little by yourself, you can make topic forms go random too with the same method.